# What does a backtick in a type name mean in the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, generics

When you `Debug.Print` some object types in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger, the output includes a backtick. What does the backtick mean?

```
Dim myList as List = a List
Debug.Print(myList.GetType().ToString()
```

**Output in Immediate Window debugger:**

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Comment: You just removed all reference to type names, making the title much more ambiguous. I liked it better before.

Comment: how about: "What does it mean when you see a backtick in a type name in the Visual Studio Debugger?"

Comment: I thought about that, but decided to just roll it back instead (no offense intended.) Just make sure to mention type names—that's the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's indicating the number of items in the subsequent array. The array contains the generic types.

`List(Of String)` has one generic type, namely *string*.

Try creating an `SomeClass(Of T as String, U as Integer)` and seeing what you get...

```
Public Class TestGeneric(Of T, U)
    Public Sub TellType(ByVal Something As T, ByVal SomethingElse As U)
        Console.WriteLine(Me.GetType())
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim MyTestGeneric As New TestGeneric(Of String, Integer)
    MyTestGeneric.TellType("Test", 3)
    Console.ReadKey(True)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
SO8593626.Program+TestGeneric`2[System.String,System.Int32]
```

Two types: String, Int

Because of the structure, it's able to represent nested generic types in a tree-like fashion...

```
    Dim MyTestGeneric As New TestGeneric(Of String, Integer)
    Dim MyOtherGeneric As New TestGeneric(Of TestGeneric(Of String, Integer), Integer)
    MyOtherGeneric.TellType(MyTestGeneric, 3)
```

outputs

```
    SO8593626.Program+TestGeneric`2[SO8593626.Program+TestGeneric`2[System.String,System.Int32],System.Int32]
```

Two root types, one of which is generic: [String, Int], Int

Comment: Here's an MSDN introduction article to generics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @akh2103 I've added an example (untested as I don't have VS to hand)

Answer (score 5):

That's part of the string representation of generics in the CLR.

The number after the backtick(`) indicates the number of generic type arguments that the type takes. The types in square brackets then indicate how those generic type arguments have been bound.